# Regular expression to allow comma and space delimited number list

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, numbers, delimited

I want to write a regular expression using javascript or jquery to allow 
comma delimited list of numbers OR 
space delimited numbers OR 
comma followed by a space delimited numbers OR
a combination of any of the above  ex
anything that is not a digit, space or comma must be rejected

SHOULD PASS
111,222,333
111 222 333
111, 222, 333
111,222,333 444 555 666, 111, 222, 333,

should NOT pass:
111,222,3a
3a
111 222 3a   etc etc

I tried the code below they seemed to work however when I typed
3a as a number, it PASSED!!!  How? I cannot understand how my code allowed that letter to pass.

I want to reject anything that is not a space, comma or digit

or is there a better way to do this without regular expressions?
I looked in google and did not find any answer.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
var isNumeric = /[\d]+([\s]?[,]?[\d])*/.test(userInput);
var isNumeric = /^[\d\s,]*/.test(userInput);    
var isNumeric = /^[\d]*[\s,]*/.test(userInput); 
var isNumeric = /^[\d\s,]*/.test(userInput);    
var isNumeric = /\d+\s*,*/.test(userInput); 

if (isNumeric == false) {
    alert(isNumeric);
  return false;
}
else
      alert('is Numeric!!!');
```

Comment: `[\d]` is exactly the same as just `\d` without the `[]`

Comment: Also the answer to your question is that you're leaving off `$` at the end of the regular expression, which means that the matched pattern may be followed by any subsequent characters.

Comment: Your test case above will only be testing the final regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would the regular expression
`^[\d,\s]+$`
not do the trick?

Comment: You need a `*` or a `+`, and multiple commas in sequence might be undesirable

Comment: Yup, just tested it and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: but I tested /^[\d\s,]*/ and it still allows 3a because it sees 3.  It is not rejecting 3a.  it is so strange.

Comment: @javafun no, that regex will not match "3a". You're still forgetting the `$` at the end of the pattern!

Comment: thank you , you are right, it seems to be working.  let me test it and get back to you.  Thank you all for your quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex... [Click to view your demo](http://rubular.com/r/pghEnVIiYX)

```
^[0-9 _ ,]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess `^(\d+[, ]+)*$` should do it.

Explanation:
A group containing one or more digits followed by at least one space or comma. Group may be repeated any number of times.

It's doesn't handle everything though, like failing when there are commas without a number between (if that's what you want).